# How to use the Worksheet_Change event for Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which contains a list of tasks, one on each row. Column A is the task name, column B is the date when it must be done and Column C is the person who must do it. Column D is used to indicate when it's been done. If this column contains anything, then the background colour for whole row should be grey, otherwise it should be white.

I'm thinking the `worksheet_change` event is the best way to handle this. I suppose I could use Conditional Formatting, but that seems to be vulnerable to breaking if cells get dragged around - I need this to be as "bullet-proof" as possible!

In pseudo-code, I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target includes a cell in column "D"
        If "D" is not empty
            Set entire row background to grey
        Else
            Set entire row background to white
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anybody give me any pointers about the best way to implement this? Am I even on the right lines, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following condition on every cell:

```
=INDIRECT("$D" & ROW())>0
```

I did some copy/pastes and dragged the cells around, and the conditional format did not break.

Answer (score 0):

**With Conditional Formatting:**

Go to `Tools->Options->General` and activate the `R1C1 reference style`

Condition: `=ISEMPTY(RC4)`

**With VBA:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim found As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim colStart As Integer
Dim colEnd As Integer

    Set found = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(4))
    colStart = 1
    colEnd = 4

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In found
            With Me.Range(Me.Cells(cell.Row, colStart), Me.Cells(cell.Row, colEnd)).Interior
                If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    .ColorIndex = 15
                Else
                    .ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
            End With
        Next cell
    End If

    Set found = Nothing
End Sub
```

I recommend using Conditional Formatting