# Why do some (but not all) Conditional Formatting "split" upon inserting rows intersecting them?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

A quick [look around](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12480934) the Internet and you can easily notice a common problem:  Conditional Formatting in Excel (2010) are often split when inserting rows that intersect the area they're formatting.

However, this "splitting" isn't consistent: **What requirement does a *Conditional Formatting* rule need to following in order to avoid being split?**

---

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. New Excel document
2. In "Sheet1":

   - Write "1" in `A1`; "2" in `A2`; and so on up to `A20`.  (I used a formula to simplify this)
3. In "Sheet2":

   - Write "2" in all the cells in the range `A3:A15`
   - Write "foobar" in all the cells in the range `B3:B15` (except `B5` and `B12` which should be empty)
   - Write "1" in `D1`; "2" in `E1`; "3" in `F1`; and so on up to `M1`.  (I used a formula to simply this)
4. In "Sheet3":

   - Write "3" in `A1`; "5" in `A2`
5. In "Sheet2" select `D3:M15`, "New Rule..." "using a formula to determine which cells to format":

   *formula:*  `=AND($B3<>"",MATCH(D$1,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$10,0))`
   *format:*   Set background FILL to bright orange.
6. In "Sheet2" select `A3:M15`, "New Rule..." "using a formula to determine which cells to format":

   *formula:*  `=AND(MOD(Sheet1!$A1,2)=0,$A3=2)`
   *format:*  Set a solid black line to the bottom border
7. You should see a line every two rows.
8. Select Row 8; Insert a row;  Enter "2" and "foobar" in the newly inserted row.  Notice how you nolonger have a line every two rows!  This is due to the conditional formatting being split in two.
9. Open the "Manage Rules" (under Conditioanl Formatting).  **Only one** of the **two** rules has been split.  **Why?!**

#### Observations

The two *Conditional Formatting* rules above are similar (i.e. both refer to cells in other sheets) and yet Excel treats them differently. Why?!

---

*Side note: The above example is used to explain the problem in a simplified context.  Offering alternatives to "formatting every other row" does not solve the problem of understand why Excel treats some rules differently than others.*

Comment: Has something to do with the ranges -- if you apply both conditional formatting rules to `A3:M15`, then both rules get split.  I'm guessing that the first cell in the row is referenced when the row selection is made, and that cell is not in the range of your second rule, so that rule is not split.

Comment: Oh this is odd, if both ranges are set to `B3:B15`, then both rules are split when the row is inserted.